# How to create a viewmodel in visual basic to pass data to shared layout?

Tags: c#, vb.net, mvvm, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

First here is an example from a previous project in c# that I am trying to mimic in visual basic.

```
public class Ticket
{
    public Ticket()
    {
        this.TicketAttachments = new HashSet<TicketAttachment>();
        this.TicketComments = new HashSet<TicketComment>();
        this.TicketHistories = new HashSet<TicketHistory>();
        this.TicketNotifications = new HashSet<TicketNotification>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTimeOffset> Updated { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TicketTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TicketPriorityId { get; set; }
    public int TicketStatusId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerUserId { get; set; }
    public string AssignedUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser OwnerUser { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser AssignedUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TicketAttachment> TicketAttachments { get;        set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TicketComment> TicketComments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TicketHistory> TicketHistories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TicketNotification> TicketNotifications { get; set; }
    public virtual TicketPriority TicketPriority { get; set; }
    public virtual TicketStatus TicketStatus { get; set; }
    public virtual TicketType TicketType { get; set; }
}

public class TicketViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<DateTimeOffset> Updated { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TicketTypeId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> TicketPriorityId { get; set; }
    public int TicketStatusId { get; set; }
    public string OwnerUserId { get; set; }
    public string AssignedUserId { get; set; }

    public TicketViewModel(Ticket ticket)
    {
        Id = ticket.Id;
        Title = ticket.Title;
        Description = ticket.Description;
        Created = ticket.Created;
        Updated = ticket.Updated;
        ProjectId = ticket.ProjectId;
        TicketTypeId = ticket.TicketTypeId;
        TicketPriorityId = ticket.TicketPriorityId;
        OwnerUserId = ticket.OwnerUserId;
        AssignedUserId = ticket.AssignedUserId;

    }

}
```

You can see how I created the model up top and a view model underneath. Now with my visual basic project I dont think I need any hashsets or virtual icollections / anything like that because I am only using one model. So far this is all I got. It works when creating a notification and displaying it on the index page but beyond that it has been giving me trouble.

```
Public Class Notification

<Key>
Public Property ID() As Integer

<Required(ErrorMessage:="Start Date Required")>
Public Property DateStart() As DateTimeOffset

Public Property DateEnd() As Nullable(Of DateTimeOffset)

<Required(ErrorMessage:="Title Required")>
Public Property Title() As String

<AllowHtml>
Public Property Message() As String

End Class
```

Controller Code

```
Namespace Controllers

    Public Class NotificationsController
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.Controller

        Private db As New ApplicationDbContext

        ' GET: Notifications
        Function Index() As ActionResult

            Return View(db.Notification.ToList())

        End Function

        ' GET: Notifications/Details/5
        Function Details(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
            If IsNothing(id) Then
                Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If
            Dim notification As Notification = db.Notification.Find(id)
            If IsNothing(notification) Then
                Return HttpNotFound()
            End If
            Return View(notification)
        End Function

        ' GET: Notifications/Create
        <Authorize>
        Function Create() As ActionResult

            Return View()
        End Function

        ' POST: Notifications/Create
        'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        'more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        <HttpPost()>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        <Authorize>
        Function Create(<Bind(Include:="ID,DateStart,DateEnd,Title,Message")> ByVal notification As Notification) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Notification.Add(notification)
                notification.DateStart = DateTimeOffset.Now
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            End If
            Return View(notification)
        End Function

        ' GET: Notifications/Edit/5
        <Authorize>
        Function Edit(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
            If IsNothing(id) Then
                Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If
            Dim notification As Notification = db.Notification.Find(id)
            If IsNothing(notification) Then
                Return HttpNotFound()
            End If
            Return View(notification)
        End Function

        ' POST: Notifications/Edit/5
        'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        'more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        <HttpPost()>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        <Authorize>
        Function Edit(<Bind(Include:="ID,DateStart,DateEnd,Title,Message")> ByVal notification As Notification) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                db.Entry(notification).State = EntityState.Modified
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            End If
            Return View(notification)
        End Function

        ' GET: Notifications/Delete/5
        <Authorize>
        Function Delete(ByVal id As Integer?) As ActionResult
            If IsNothing(id) Then
                Return New HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            End If
            Dim notification As Notification = db.Notification.Find(id)
            If IsNothing(notification) Then
                Return HttpNotFound()
            End If
            Return View(notification)
        End Function

        ' POST: Notifications/Delete/5
        <Authorize>
        <HttpPost()>
        <ActionName("Delete")>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Function DeleteConfirmed(ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
            Dim notification As Notification = db.Notification.Find(id)
            db.Notification.Remove(notification)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        End Function

        Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
            If (disposing) Then
                db.Dispose()
            End If
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

View Code

```
@ModelType IEnumerable(Of Notification)


<!-- Notification Area -->
                            <div class="mail-us top-bar-block">
                                <i class="glyphicon-alert" style="color:red" id="form1"></i>
                                <span id="message" style="display: none; color:red">
                                    <span>
                                        @For Each item In Model
                                            @<tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    @Html.DisplayFor(Function(modelItem) item.Title)
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        Next
                                    </span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
```

Comment: Define "giving me trouble"

Comment: Check your tags.  VBA <> VB.net.  VBA is a specific language for MS Office applications.

Comment: there are conflicts in my notifications controller when I try to return view(db.Notifications.ToList()) on my notifications/create page for instance. My notifications index page it is scafollded out like that and it works. I made sure the top is ModelType IEnumberable(Of Notification) but the model is empty (I get an object reference is not set to an instance of an object error on my For Each loop on my shared layout). Why is it empty on one page and not on the other?

Comment: Where is the View code, and the Controller code?

Comment: @petethepagan-gerbil I added the view and controller code.